# How to reset and delete ACL permissions for account?

Tags: c#, .net, acl

OS Windows 7 SP1 x64

I set ACL permissions to my folder for some account:

```
var accessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(account,
    fileSystemRights: FileSystemRights.Modify,
    inheritanceFlags: InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit |
    InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
    propagationFlags: PropagationFlags.None,
    type: AccessControlType.Allow);

// Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the 
// current security settings.
DirectorySecurity dSecurity = directoryinfo.GetAccessControl();

// Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings.
dSecurity.AddAccessRule(accessRule);

// Set the new access settings.
directoryinfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

At this case I allowed read and write for account. It works fine.

But later I wanted to change the rights for that account: to allow read only permissions. I use such code:

```
var accessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(account,
    fileSystemRights: FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute,
    inheritanceFlags: InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit |
    InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
    propagationFlags: PropagationFlags.None,
    type: AccessControlType.Allow);

// Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the 
// current security settings.
DirectorySecurity dSecurity = directoryinfo.GetAccessControl();

// Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings.
dSecurity.AddAccessRule(accessRule);

// Set the new access settings.
directoryinfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

But the account has write permissions still. How can I fix it? Also, how can I remove the ACL permissions for that account when I will want to do it later?

Comment: There are various aptly named `ResetAccessRule` and `RemoveAccessRule` in `DirectorySecurity`... I would start from there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy:

```
dSecurity = directoryinfo.GetAccessControl();

accessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(account,
    fileSystemRights: FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute,
    inheritanceFlags: InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit |
    InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
    propagationFlags: PropagationFlags.None,
    type: AccessControlType.Allow);

dSecurity.SetAccessRule(accessRule);
directoryinfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

and for removing:

```
dSecurity = directoryinfo.GetAccessControl();

accessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(account, 0, 0);
dSecurity.RemoveAccessRuleAll(accessRule);
directoryinfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

Note that the `SetAccessRule` will work even if there is no access rule for the `account` (so it can even be used to do the initial `Add`)